# tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator with Tf.Hub failure

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to convert model to process B64 images instead of JSON I'm using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`

```
tf-nightly version:

Version:  1.15.0-dev20190714
Eager mode:  True
Hub version:  0.5.0
GPU is available
```

Based on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/hub_with_keras) tutorial

I created a Keras model using tf.Hub layer:

https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4

Converting to estimator:

```
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
    keras_model_path=h5_model_path,
    custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer},
    model_dir=tf_model_path)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer
```

Model summary:

```
model.summary()

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
keras_layer (KerasLayer)     (None, 1280)              2257984   
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 5)                 6405      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,264,389
Trainable params: 6,405
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
```

If I pass the Keras model object:

```
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
    keras_model=model,
    custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer},
    model_dir=tf_model_path)
```

I get:

```
FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable save_counter from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/save_counter/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node save_counter/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
  (1) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable save_counter from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/save_counter/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node save_counter/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
     [[MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_15/project/weights/Read/ReadVariableOp/_2363]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Comment: hey did you found any solution?

Comment: It's a bug, will be fixed this month